# Fastest way to convert incoming image data buffer to bitmap (using Winform C# and Aforge library)

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing, aforge

I have a project and this I have two webcams that going to send frame and in then the program need to extract few lines colors in frames
I'm using **[Aforge](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/)** library for this and i have edited the Aforge.Video.DirectShow methodes and now the sender event will send for me the webcam frame data buffer and length !

- I have problem converting these webcam frame buffer data to bitmap !

  ```
    private unsafe Bitmap extract_frame(IntPtr buffer_ptr, int buffer_length)
    {
        Bitmap image = null;
        image = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(new UnmanagedMemoryStream((byte*)buffer_ptr, buffer_length) );
        return image;
     }
  ```

This Project is part of safety human project and its important to process on frames very fast , now the time of this convert process is something about 1.30ms

After little try i found that when i set ***InvalidateImageData = false*** , the problem will solve and the process time will something about 0.5ms and this is good
but the next problem after do this happen in extract color in another method that contains the frame of this method
and there the LockBit process take a lot time (~1.2ms) and if I set ***InvalidateImageData = true*** in main method the problem will solve and the ***LockBit*** take a time about ~0.4ms but I'll faced with first problem again !

```
    image = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(new UnmanagedMemoryStream((byte*)buffer_ptr, buffer_length), false, false);
    //  validateimageData = false and this serction work well but lock bit take time
```

- Why the lockbit process take time when InvalidateImageData is false in **Bitmap.FromStream** ?
- Is there any faster way to convert image data buffers(JPG or JPEG) in  Bitmap ?

Comment: First of all, why are you worrying about 1.3ms? at 30fps you should have 30ms to do any processing, 1.3ms is well within this time. Secondly, I would assume that the output should be raw pixel-data, not any jpeg or otherwise encoded data. Are you sure the bottleneck is not in some other part of the program?

Comment: Cause I have 2 webcams in my app .  And yes I'm sure the problem come from this part cause this is the first thing on new frame come

Comment: If I can replace the Bitmap.FromStream with a faster way , the problem will be solved

Comment: First of all, you need to consider the whole image pipeline, it is perfectly possible for small changes to one part to have an effect on other parts. I find it highly suspect that an improvement of 0.8ms would have any significant effect on a 30fps stream. Some profiling would probably be in order. One potential issue is creating a bitmap each frame, a better approach should be to just copy the raw pixel data to an existing bitmap. Thus avoiding allocation/garbage collection overhead.

Comment: Yes that's right , and I have another question , I can't understand what ValidateImageData parameter(in FromStream) do , cause when I set it false in FromStream  the process time down to ~0.5 (As I explain in top) , What is this i couldn't understand why this happen .